# Angular 2 auxiliary router has error(s) on browser reload

Tags: angular, router, angular2-routing

After hours of Angular-wrangling I have successfully created functioning auxiliary child routes which I have made reusable throughout my app. Sort of.

The auxiliary routes work perfectly upon initial page load, and they are indeed affecting the browser history. However, if I reload the URL (or include auxiliary references in an initial load) I get a file not found error for main.js.

The reason for the error is obvious because I can plainly see that my app is attempting to get `http://*RootDirectory*/*CurrentURL*/*AppDirectory*/main.js`.

The app for some reason thinks that the `CurrentURL` is the `RootDirectory` when it tries to load `main.js`. It was also initially failing to load all of my linked files from `index.html`, but I fixed that by changing their paths to refer to my site root.

I assume I could solve this issue with `main.js` in the same way, but I can't figure out where this incorrect relative path is because Angular2 (for all of its glory) sucks pooping rectum at providing coherent error messages!

Here are the things that I already tried:

- Changing my outDir to an absolute path in tsconfig.
- Changing my main app package to an absolute path in my systemjs config.
- Remembering what else I already tried.
- Jumping out of my office window.

kThxBye

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this easily by implementing `HashLocationStrategy` which adds `#` to all your routes, so `http://RootDirectory/CurrentURL` becomes `http://RootDirectory/#/CurrentURL`. You achieve this by adding `HashLocationStrategy` to `AppModule` providers:

```
{ provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy }
```

You need to import `LocationStrategy` and `HashLocationStrategy` from `@angular/common`:

```
import { LocationStrategy, HashLocationStrategy } from '@angular/common';
```

You can read more about it [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#browser-url-styles).

Comment: Thanks for the very prompt response! It worked perfectly. But now how do I make the URLs pretty again?

Comment: @Smaft I'm not sure, I know you have to change configuration of your server, but don't know what exactly.